# .mov could not be played - cloudfront.net

Tags: error-handling, video-streaming, jwplayer, amazon-cloudfront, .mov

I'm using JW player to play some video files on the web but these specific 3 .mov videos are acting weird though the other 2 .mov files are playing okay. Looking at the console, seems like they're always redirected to cloudfront.net. 
I've tried converting .mov to .mp4 since I have another video with this format that works fine but still the video could not be played.
I think it's the videos themselves that's defective but I don't know why since they would play fine on a player but not on the web.
Can anyone share why this is doing so?